# WINDOWS.H already included error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compilation

I get an error when trying to compile a small c++ program
Error   87  fatal error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include     c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h   16

I made sure that the windows.h was not included in any of the project files I have. I am using a visual studio 2008 IDE

Any reason why ?

Answer (score 16):

reason why is because something *is* including Windows.h: the compiler is not lying to you.

Go to project Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced and set Show Includes to Yes. Then build, and the compiler will show you a list with every included file found, and in the order it finds it, hereby telling you which file eventually includes windows.h

Comment: Thanks ! I found the afxwin.h header to include windows.h . However I require this header for the AfxGetInstanceHandle that I use. So, I would require it to be included.

Answer (score 9):

try and include **afxcoll.h** before **stdafx.h**. I had the same problem and it fixed it.
See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/2ab6862f-0d90-467a-b283-f62f6aef96fe/ for the original discussion.

Comment: including **afxcol.h** before **atlstr.h** in my stdafx.h file fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

```
#include "afxwin.h"         // MFC core and standard components
#include "afxext.h"         // MFC extensions
```

Adding these to my stdafx.h file sorted out that error..hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio by default will defile your program with a precompiled headers file, which may contain something which includes something which includes windows.h . Be sure to check in there.

Comment: found that including afxwin.h was throwing the error. However I do require afxwin.h for AfxGetInstanceHandle() function that I use ... is there a workaround ?

Comment: do you use precompiled headers? If so, can't you just #include "stdafx.h" to pull in the declaration of AfxGetInstanceHandle()?

Answer (score 1):

In your project go to Configuration Properties->C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers. Make sure the Precompiled Header setting  is set to **Use(/Yu)**.

This  setting "Enables creation or use of a precompiled header during the build".

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was the "stdafx.h" file is being included in the "StdAfx.h" file, and the file name in Configuration Properties->C/C++ ->Precompiled Headers was never updated from "stdafx.h" to "StdAfx.h".